# Disabling the back button and refresh button using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I don't have any idea.

Suggest me code for disabling the back and refresh button in my application.

Help me with code*

Comment: Can you please provide some code. And your tries so that other can make suggestions and find bugs or provide correct way to solution

Comment: @Revansiddh I didn't even try this. I don't have any idea.. suggest me some

Comment: Some example that you have to say about your question: 1. provide your written code. 2. provide more information to respondents to help you better. 3. Please prevent to talking about your ideas and talking about a real knot that you have now. good luck

Comment: @SriHariKarthikVijayakumar back button in which application ? are you talking about mobile app or web

Comment: @Revansiddh reactjs means its web application  if its react native means mobile application

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use `state` variables to enable and disable button. 
Look in below enable if you click `reset` or `reload` it will toggle

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  state = {
    isResetDisable: false,
    isReloadDisable: false,
  }
  handleButtonPress(token){
     console.log(token+" "+"pressed")
  }
  render(){
    return(
     <div>
         <div>
            <a onClick={()=>this.setState({isResetDisable: !this.state.isResetDisable})}> Click Reset lable to toggle button
            </a>
                <input disabled={this.state.isResetDisable}  type="button" value={this.state.isResetDisable ? 'Reset Disabled' : 'Reset Enable'} onClick={()=>{this.handleButtonPress('reset')}}/>
         </div>       
         
           
         <div>
          
           <a onClick={()=>this.setState({isReloadDisable: !this.state.isReloadDisable})}> Click Reload lable to toggle button
            </a>
                <input disabled={this.state.isReloadDisable}  type="button" value={this.state.isReloadDisable ? 'Reload Disabled' : 'Reload Enable'} onClick={()=>this.handleButtonPress('reload')}/>
                
         </div>
         
     </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```